# Mongodb Text Search Processed Query

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I'm using the text search feature and I couldn't find a way to get the stemmed terms in the query. Is there a way to also return the list of words in the stemmed form together with the query results and also the parts of the document that matched the result? This would be meaningful to understand and identify which part of the document matches.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As of MongoDB 2.6, the only meta information about the text search that can be used is a score indicating the strength of the match. You can submit a ticket on the [Core Server project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) to request this feature (as I looked and I don't think one exists at the moment).

Comment: Hey, posted there. Thanks ;)